# JCR Content using Jackrabbit with Moqui - no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data):

Tags: content-management-system, jcr, jackrabbit, moqui

Moqui Version : 2.1.3
Jackrabbit Version: jackrabbit-standalone-2.20.2.jar

I'm trying to use Jackrabbit for content with Moqui, I followed the /moqui/bin/runtime/jackrabbit/README.md guide and Jackrabbit is up and running as below

> 06:48:48.501  INFO         main   o.moqui.i.t.JackrabbitRunToolFactory
> Initializing Jackrabbit 06:48:48.502  INFO         main
> o.moqui.i.t.JackrabbitRunToolFactory Starting Jackrabbit 06:49:15.094
> INFO         main .moqui.i.c.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl Cache Facade
> initialized 06:49:15.427  INFO         main
> o.moqui.i.c.ResourceFacadeImpl Using xsl-fo-handler-factory FOP
> (org.moqui.fop.FopToolFactory) 06:49:16.275  INFO         main
> o.moqui.i.c.ResourceFacadeImpl Added JCR Repository main of type
> org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.RmiRepositoryFactory$1 for
> workspace default using parameters:
> [org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri:http://localhost:8081/rmi]
> 06:49:17.824  INFO         main         o.moqui.i.c.ResourceFacadeImpl
> Added JCR Repository main of type
> org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.RepositoryImpl for workspace default
> using parameters:
> [org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2davex.uri:http://localhost:8081/server]
> 06:49:17.824  INFO         main .moqui.i.c.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl
> Resource Facade initialized

[image: http://localhost:8081/server/default/jcr%3aroot/]

After the above setup, i'm trying to add a new Wiki Space under Hivemind Admin > Wiki Space to a JCR repository and selecting content://main/WikiSpace as the Root Page Directory in the below screen
[image: http://localhost:8080/qapps/hmadmin/WikiSpace/WikiSpaces]
and getting the below error
[image: Error while adding a Wiki Space to JCR Content Repository using Jackrabbit]

And the Moqui Server has the below error message

> 07:06:25.931  WARN 227229563-78        o.moqui.i.s.ServiceCallSyncImpl Error running service org.moqui.impl.WikiServices.create#WikiSpace (Throwable) Artifact stack: org.moqui.impl.WikiServices.create#WikiSpace, component://SimpleScreens/screen/SimpleScreens/Wiki/WikiSpaces.xml/createSpace, component://SimpleScreens/screen/SimpleScreens/Wiki/WikiSpaces.xml, component://HiveMind/screen/HiveMindAdmin/WikiSpace.xml, component://HiveMind/screen/HiveMindAdmin.xml, component://webroot/screen/webroot/apps.xml, component://webroot/screen/webroot.xml
> javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.nodetype.ItemDefinitionProviderImpl.getQPropertyDefinition(ItemDefinitionProviderImpl.java:233) ~[jackrabbit-jcr2spi-2.12.1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.nodetype.ItemDefinitionProviderImpl.getQPropertyDefinition(ItemDefinitionProviderImpl.java:126) ~[jackrabbit-jcr2spi-2.12.1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.NodeImpl.getApplicablePropertyDefinition(NodeImpl.java:1831) ~[jackrabbit-jcr2spi-2.12.1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.NodeImpl.createProperty(NodeImpl.java:1518) ~[jackrabbit-jcr2spi-2.12.1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.NodeImpl.setProperty(NodeImpl.java:252) ~[jackrabbit-jcr2spi-2.12.1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.NodeImpl.setProperty(NodeImpl.java:232) ~[jackrabbit-jcr2spi-2.12.1.jar:?]
> at org.moqui.impl.context.reference.ContentResourceReference.putObject(ContentResourceReference.groovy:177) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.context.reference.ContentResourceReference.putText(ContentResourceReference.groovy:147) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org_moqui_impl_WikiServices_create_WikiSpace.run(org_moqui_impl_WikiServices_create_WikiSpace:20) ~[?:?]
> at org.moqui.impl.actions.XmlAction.run(XmlAction.java:67) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.service.runner.InlineServiceRunner.runService(InlineServiceRunner.java:59) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.service.ServiceCallSyncImpl.callSingle(ServiceCallSyncImpl.java:322) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.service.ServiceCallSyncImpl.call(ServiceCallSyncImpl.java:125) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at component___SimpleScreens_screen_SimpleScreens_Wiki_WikiSpaces_xml_transition_createSpace_service_call.run(component___SimpleScreens_screen_SimpleScreens_Wiki_WikiSpaces_xml_transition_createSpace_service_call:7) ~[?:?]
> at org.moqui.impl.actions.XmlAction.run(XmlAction.java:67) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenDefinition$TransitionItem.run(ScreenDefinition.groovy:839) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:748) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:744) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:744) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:744) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.recursiveRunTransition(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:744) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.internalRender(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:454) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.render(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:170) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.service(MoquiServlet.groovy:167) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[moqui_temp7168891208283816662execlib_javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar.:3.1.0]
> at org.moqui.impl.webapp.ElasticRequestLogFilter.doFilter(ElasticRequestLogFilter.groovy:110) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
> 07:06:25.935 ERROR 227229563-78          o.moqui.i.c.MessageFacadeImpl no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data
> 07:06:25.937  WARN 227229563-78      o.moqui.i.c.TransactionFacadeImpl Transaction rollback for [no matching property definition found for {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}data
> ]. Here is the current location:
> org.moqui.BaseException: Rollback location
> at org.moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl.rollback(TransactionFacadeImpl.groovy:470) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl.rollback(TransactionFacadeImpl.groovy:443) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.internalRender(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:463) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.screen.ScreenRenderImpl.render(ScreenRenderImpl.groovy:170) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at org.moqui.impl.webapp.MoquiServlet.service(MoquiServlet.groovy:167) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[moqui_temp7168891208283816662execlib_javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar.:3.1.0]
> at org.moqui.impl.webapp.ElasticRequestLogFilter.doFilter(ElasticRequestLogFilter.groovy:110) ~[moqui-framework-3.0.0-rc8.jar:3.0.0-rc8]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]

Am i missing any setup, Appreciate any pointers, Also note i'm able to add new Wiki Space to the dbresource as below
[image]

Comment: Sharing my troubleshooting results, Version: jackrabbit-standalone-2.20.2.jar, As per the builtin_nodetypes.cnd the jcr:data under nt:resource is BINARY [as below] 
[nt:resource] > mix:mimeType, mix:lastModified, mix:referenceable
  primaryitem jcr:data
  - jcr:data (BINARY) mandatory; however ContentResourceReference.groovy is considering this as a String during initial save > if (obj instanceof CharSequence) {
           ////fileContent.setProperty("jcr:data", session.valueFactory.createValue(obj.toString()))
        } and is causing this issue, the above needs to be converted to Binary

Comment: With the above change, i got past the error and I'm happy to share a patch if the framework team wants to consider the above resolution.